# Does woocommerce auto-update the stock quantity of a product after the product is bought?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce, stock

I have an ecommerce website and I want to disable the catalog mode and start selling products. Now I've the maintenance moda active.

I'm using woocommerce plugin with wordpress. I tried many time to simulate a order but the problem is that the quantity in the stock doesn't update.

For example:
I have 5 red Medium t-shirts and 3 X-Large. If a user try to buy 1 M and 1 XL the stock should auto-decrement the quantity of that t-shirt: 4 M and 2 XL. I want to do this operation automatically, after the payment is completed. Does woocommerce allow this operation? Or, for every order, should I go to the orders menu in wordpress and click the "process" button?

Thank you.

Comment: The product stock will decrement automatically if stock management is enabled at product level and once the Order get one of the following status: "pending", "on-hold", "processing" or "completed"

Answer (score 0):

It should decrement automatically. For example, I'm currently developing a website where I have subscription products, and each time the renewal is proceeding it is sending me an email which says that 1 unity of the subscription product has been decremented.